# Sticky Footer menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve pretty much the opposite of a Sticky Header

**Sticky Header:** No action on page load, Stick `top:0` when Y-offset position reached on scroll.

**Sticky Footer Menu:** Stick `bottom:0` on page load, Un-Stick when Y-offset position reached on scroll.

Here is [my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdwpo1wn/)

**Issues I need help with:**

1 - I need it to stick to bottom of screen .onload rather than .onscroll

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
// replaced with this but no luck = window.onload = function(){myFunction()};
```

2 - I need it to un-stick when you scroll down and it reaches it's original position on the page.

```
// Get the offset position of the footermenu
var sticky = footermenu.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header, remove when its scroll position
// is reached - something here must be incorrect. 
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        footermenu.classList.remove("sticky");
    } else {
        footermenu.classList.add("sticky");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should save the initial footer position and then make it sticky:

```
var sticky = footermenu.offsetTop;
footermenu.classList.add("sticky");
```

Then to check if the page reached that position:

```
if (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= sticky + footermenu.clientHeight)
```

Here I add `window.innerHeight` because `window.pageYOffset` is counted from the top of the page, and you need the bottom position.

Try the following code:

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// replaced with this but no luck = window.onload = function(){myFunction()};

// Get the header
var footermenu = document.getElementById("myFootermenu");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = footermenu.offsetTop;

footermenu.classList.add("sticky");

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= sticky + footermenu.clientHeight) {
    footermenu.classList.remove("sticky");
  } else {
    footermenu.classList.add("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the header */
.footermenu {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the header gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

/* Top container styling only */
.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>


</body>
<div class="footermenu" id="myFootermenu">
  <h2>Footer Menu</h2>
</div>
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Selected as correct answer. Works perfectly here and in Fiddle, when I apply to [this page](http://40sreboot.thedigitalpine.co.uk/) - it does not unstick after scrolling past the threshold. Currently trying to figure out why it doesn't work when applied to the page

Comment: @CemTorun I think it's because `var sticky = footermenu.offsetTop;` is calculated before the layout is complete. Unfortunatelly I don't know what exactly is going on... But I can suggest you to put all this code inside a `$(document).ready` function. Also check the position of your footer before it becomes 'sticky', try to debug it using devtools

Comment: No worries will have a go. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. you need to pass var inside function(sticky){ // your code }

```js
// Get the header
var footermenu = document.getElementById("myFootermenu");
// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = footermenu.offsetTop;
myFunction(sticky);
window.onscroll  = function() {myFunction2(sticky)};

// replaced with this but no luck = window.onload = function(){myFunction()};
// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position

function myFunction(sticky) {
 if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    footermenu.classList.remove("sticky");
  } else {
    footermenu.classList.add("sticky");
  }
}
function myFunction2(sticky) {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    footermenu.classList.remove("sticky");
  } else {
    footermenu.classList.add("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the header */
.footermenu {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the header gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

/* Top container styling only */
.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>


</body>
<div class="footermenu" id="myFootermenu">
  <h2>Footer Menu</h2>
</div>
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn’t actually demonstrate the footer being un-stuck after scrolling down far enough. Did you forget to change something in the snippet’s code?

Comment: its will un-stuck when you load this in browser.
in Snippet Code height is properly counted because its taking height of specific snippet window.
if you run this script in browser it will un-stuck.
to verify without running in brower 

add 
console.log(window.pageYOffset.":".sticky);

if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
//add console line here
    footermenu.classList.remove("sticky");
} else {
    footermenu.classList.add("sticky");}

Answer (score -1):

Can what you're trying be accomplished with CSS position sticky?

```
footer { position: sticky; bottom: 0; }
```

That will be sticky on load, and it will not overlay the content like position fixed would (which is why I suspect you want it to *un*stick at a certain point).

[It has about 75% browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) according to caniuse, and will gracefully degrade on browsers that don't support it.

Comment: Based on @CemTorun's description in the question, no, a plain `position: sticky` won't work. They want the footer to be un-stuck after scrolling down far enough, but `position: sticky` never un-sticks the element after scrolling down further.